# Upload file to Documentum via .NET API

Tags: .net, sharepoint, documentum

I am looking to upload a file from SharePoint to documentum via .NET API and looking for possible options.

I have come across these solutions:

- Interop Assemblies for Documentum (I have heard they will be deprecated)
- [This](http://documentum.codeplex.com/releases/view/55281) codeplex solution

Can anyone tell me the preferred approaches and their associated protocols (HTTP, TCP ) ?

Comment: What version of Documentum?  You might also try Documentum Foundation Services (DFS) which are HTTP SOAP-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not familiar with Documentum, but theoretically you can upload files to any system if you can perform HttpRequest's (PUT operations). Here's an example:

```
string localFilename = "<path to file you wish to upload>";
// ex. c:\temp\myFileToUpload.doc

FileStream myStream = new FileStream(localFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader myReader = new BinaryReader(myStream);
byte[] bytesToOutput = reader.ReadBytes((int)myStream.Length);
myReader.Close();
myStream.Close();

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    client.UploadData(uploadPath, "PUT", bytesToOutput);
}
```